# notation in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I was reading a paper, and I found a notation that I don't understand:
$\mathbb{E}[| \textbf{S} |] $, where $\textbf{S}$ is a set. Are there any differences with the notation $\mathbb{E}[formula]$ (I always read this notation like the set of edges such that the formula is true for the edges).
Moreover, what does the notation $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]$, where $\textbf{X} \in \mathbb N$, mean?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\mathbb E[X]$ denotes the expected value of a random variable $X$.

Answer (score 4):

By ChatGPT: In the notation E[|S|], the expression |S| denotes the cardinality or the number of elements in the set S. So, E[|S|] means the expected value of the number of elements in the set S.

On the other hand, the notation E[formula] refers to the expected value of a random variable defined by the formula. For example, if the formula is X + Y, where X and Y are random variables, then E[X + Y] represents the expected value of the sum of X and Y.

Regarding the notation E[X], where X∈N, it means the expected value of a discrete random variable X that takes non-negative integer values. In other words, E[X] represents the average value of X when X can only take on values of 0, 1, 2, and so on.